# twitter application development : PHP or javascript...please help

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

What is the preferred method for twitter application development

Using Javascript or using PHP

Is it true we can do more things if we use PHP instead of Javascript

Is any one of them going to be deprecated in future

Efforrts Appreciated Thanks!!!

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: Well right now just basic functionalities but later on I am looking to build something more interesting and smart !! but I want to start with right thing even if it is difficult in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.  If you want something that will do basic grabbing of tweets, probably JS.  If you want to do smarter things like count keywords, then you'll need PHP.

Will either of them be deprecated?  You'd have to ask Twitter, and hope they don't change their minds.  They can turn anything off at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using PHP and javascript in a web application the paramount difference is:

PHP runs on the server. JS runs on the client.

You could also run JS files on the server, but this isn't the usual way.

JS will cause traffic from the client to the web servers it connects. JS is very attackable as it is run where you have no control. Web browsers are sometimes a bit conservative if you use JS to poll data from different domains (basically they ask first the target server if it allows this behaviour).

PHP will cause traffic from your server to the servers it connects. It is harder to attack as you have (almost) full control over it.

If you could specify more in detail what kind of application you are intending to do, perhaps the choice would be easier.

Comment: thanks for the answer ..... good point, you are correct ... but it connects to the twitter server so dont you think twitter will take care of security ??

Comment: Basically twitter is interested that people connect to their servers. Correct me if I am wrong. Why should they care?

Comment: Well, the do care because if a server is in the way, they don't have accurate trackback stats (with JS they can identify the viewer, with the server solution, they can't).  They're still up in the air right now as far as what they're doing, because their business models are still... lackluster.

Comment: @John - True. When using a server application to heavily poll twitter (or similar), one should maybe take into consideration sending HTTP-Headers that more or less look like being sent from a normal client and change them frequently (rotate through a list of possible values for User-Agent for instance). You could also make use of onion routing, so the request come every x minutes from another IP, unless twitter controls all TOR end points.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a choice, I'd say JS is better as it's considerably faster through it's asynchronous nature.

Comment: Can we achieve everything through that we could through php cuz according to the previous answer php seems more powerful !!

Comment: JS is not asynchronous by nature, and you can also run asynchronous tasks with php...